# How do I fix this code (due to MySql deprecated)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have written this login system, but there is one big problem. Everytime I try to get the $errors to print when the values inputted are contradictory to the code, it doesn't work. This is the user login code

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fill out this field!';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Are you sure you\'ve registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'you haven\'t activated your account!';
    } else {
    //Login com.
   }

print_r($errors);
}

?>
```

So I don't see any problems here. Where I suspect problems to be are here. This is the general file:

```
<?php
function sanitize($data) {
return mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>
```

and here is the users code:

```
<?php

function user_active($username, $con){ 
    $username = sanitize($username, $con);

    $q = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)
      FROM `users`
      WHERE `username` = '{$username}'
      AND `active` = 1";
 if($query = mysqli_query($con, $q)){
     return (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) ? true : false;
  } else {
     //TODO: Replace in production
      trigger_error('<p>Query ' . mysqli_error($con) . '</p>');
    }
}

  ?>
```

This is the connect code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db($con, 'users');
?>
```

I know that MySql is deprecated so I converted to MySqli but it just caused more problems as the codes kept contradicting each other. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "values inputted are contradictory to the code"?

Comment: Your use of [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) appears to be incorrect - it needs a connection passed to it.

Comment: `sanitize()` functional parameters vary in declaration and definition. It should be correct.

Comment: Don't you think mysqli_error() will give mysqli errors?

Comment: How would I correct the escape string?

Comment: Oh of course! I need 2 parameters for the mysqli string. But I can't seem to figure out the mysqli string to place in the ().

Comment: Thank you Antony, I made another blind mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify like this,

```
<?php
   function sanitize($data, $con) { //$con parameter added
     return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data); //$con parameter added
   } 
?>
```

[Read out here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-notes)

Comment: Oh god thank you. One question, before I posted this question I set it up with two parameters but like this: ($con, $data); but it didn't work. Does the placement matter here, I am not very familiar with MySqli (been using MySql for these past few years) Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome . :) Yes. `$con` variable comes first. Read out the link from my answer.

Comment: @JellalSaleh: yes, the order matters in nearly all PHP functions. There are one or two where parameters can be in any order - they are a historical oddity. Always read the manual to check the order of the parameters, and you'll be fine!

Comment: @halfer Thank you, I knew something was up. Can't believe I missed that haha!